# Show data in rows and columns in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to show my data in rows and columns. Number of columns are constant i.e 4, but number of rows are dynamic. How can I create such a table with 4 columns and multiple rows according to the data. Is there any API that could create table or what is the simple option for this?

Comment: are the columns meant to be scrolled independently ??

Comment: No.It seems like a table wit data

Comment: then as Nikolai stated you could use a collection view , or design a custom cell so that it looks like it has four columns within

Comment: Well, UITableView comes to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this control, customize according to your need, get link fom
[CocoaControl.com](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mynstickyflowlayout)[image]

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches:

1. A `UICollectionView` (in conjunction with a flow layout) is made for this purpose.
2. A tiny bit simpler but also more restricted: Using a `UITableView` with a custom cell that holds the four cells for each column.

Comment: Please give me an example or any tutorial.

Comment: The question becomes.. "How do I use UITableView", which has hundreds of questions and guides in each and every corner of the internet

Comment: I have to email this table(data with rows and columns) actually.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshanAnwar, so you need to generate a document (for instance, PDF), that you would be able to send via e-mail?